# sampling pandas dataframe by different frequencies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index series/dataframe with ID and timestamp as key. This data structure has daily data for various IDs. Can I use the resample function to look at end of the month snapshot of this data structure ?

```
ID ts           value 
1  2001-01-30   1
   2001-01-31   2
   2001-02-01   3
2  2001-01-30   3
   2001-01-31   2
   2001-02-01   4
```

I want this output

```
ID  ts          value
1   2001-01-31  2
2   2001-01-31  2
```

Can I use the resample function call to help me out? I know I can create end of the month date list and loop through those dates and find those values. But I want to use the full functionality of pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to resample? Just set the index to `ts` and then slice, like so:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
raw = """id  ts     value
1  2001-01-30   1
1  2001-01-31   2
1  2001-02-01   3
2  2001-01-30   3
2  2001-01-31   2
2  2001-02-01   4"""
sio = StringIO(raw)
df = read_csv(sio, sep=r'\s+', header=0, parse_dates=[1])
df.set_index('ts', inplace=True)
```

Slice and then reset the index:

```
print df['2001-01-31'].reset_index().set_index('id')
```

resulting in:

```
                    ts  value
id                           
1  2001-01-31 00:00:00      2
2  2001-01-31 00:00:00      2
```

If you don't care that the end of month values will be inferred if they don't exist then you can do this:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).resample('M', how='last')
```

which gives

```
            id  value
ts                   
2001-01-31   1      2
2001-02-28   1      3
2001-01-31   2      2
2001-02-28   2      4
```